# Biodiversity, environment and ecology - Yajur Veda

Tags: yajur-veda

This article mentions about [biodiversity, environment and ecology in the Yajur Veda](https://www.academia.edu/16028337/VEDIC_SCIENCE_AND_ENVIRONMENT)

> Knowledge of biodiversity, interrelation between living species and
>   the environment, the need to maintain natural dynamism, and the
>   natural way of transgressing the ecological principles are mentioned
>   in Yajur-veda.

What Shlokas of the Yajur Veda confirm or deny the above statement?